# Blocking a load balanced server environment from sending two emails

Tags: java, spring, cron, semaphore

I am currently working on a scheduled task that runs behind the scenes of my Spring web application.  The task uses a cron scheduler to execute at midnight every night, and clean-up unused applications for my portal (my site allows users to create an application to fill out, and if they don't access the form within 30 days, my background task will delete it from our DB and inform the user to create a new form if needed with an email).  Everything works great in my test environment, and I am ready to move to QA.

However, my next environment uses two load balanced servers to process requests.  This is a problem, as the cron scheduler and my polling task run concurrently on both servers.  While the read/writes to the DB won't be an issue, the issue lies with sending the notification email to the application user.  Without any polling locks, two emails have the possibility to be generated and sent, and I would like to avoid this.  Normally, we would use a SQL stored procedure and have a field in our DB for a lock, and then set/release whenever the polling code is called, so only one instance of the polling will be executed.  However, with my new polling task, we don't have any fields available, so I am trying to work on a SPRING solution.  I found this resource online:

http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/threading.html

And I was thinking of using it as

```
Semaphore _pollingLock = new Semaphore(1);
_pollingLock.aquire();

try {
    //run my polling task
}
finally {
    //release lock
}
```

However, I'm not sure if this will just ensure the second instance executes after, or it skips the second instance and will never execute.  Or, is this solution not even appropriate, and there is a better solution.  Again, I am using Spring java framework, so any solution that exists there would be my best bet.

Comment: The Semaphore will synchronize among threads not among processes on different machines. Depending on your database and transaction isolation level, you could use blocking reads so that the second process cannot read the rows that have been selected for update by the first.

Comment: @SergioMontoro We are currently looking in to this solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two ways that we've handled this sort of problem in the past both start with designating one of our clustered servers as the one responsible for a specific task (say, sending email, or running a job).

In one solution, we set a JVM parameter on all clustered servers identifying the server name of the one server on which your process should run.  For example -DemailSendServer=clusterMember1

In another solution, we simply provided a JVM parameter in the startup of this designated server alone. For example -DsendEmailFromMe=true

In both cases, you can add a tiny bit of code in your process to gate it based on the value or presence of the startup parameter.

I've found the second option simpler to use since the presence of the parameter is enough to allow the process to run. In the first solution, you would have to compare the current server name against the value of the parameter instead.

We haven't done much with Spring Batch, but I would assume there is a way to configure Batch to run a job on a single server within a cluster as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Unfortunately, this environment is not a server cluster, and the only thing shared between the two is the DB.  So anything that is set in one environment can't be reached by the other (I realized this after consulting with a team member who is more familiar with the infrastructure than I am).